# genfromtxt dtype=None returns wrong shape

Tags: csv, numpy, genfromtxt

I'm a newcomer to numpy, and am having a hard time reading CSVs into a numpy array with genfromtxt.

I found a CSV file on the web that I'm using as an example. It's a mixture of floats and strings. It's here: http://pastebin.com/fMdRjRMv

I'm using numpy via pylab (initializing on a Ubuntu system via: ipython -pylab). numpy.version.version is 1.3.0.

Here's what I do:

**Example #1:**

```
data = genfromtxt("fMdRjRMv.txt", delimiter=',', dtype=None)

data.shape

(374, 15)


data[10,10] ## Take a look at an example element

'30'

type(data[10,10])

type 'numpy.string_'
```

There are no errant quotation marks in the CSV file, so I've no idea why it should think that the number is a string. Does anyone know why this is the case?

**Example #2 (skipping the first row):**

data = genfromtxt("fMdRjRMv.txt", delimiter=',', dtype=None, skiprows=1)

data.shape

(373,)

Does anyone know why it would not read all of this into a 1-dimensional array?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your example #1, the problem is that all the values in a single column must share the same datatype. Since the first line of your data file has the column names, this means that the datatype of every column is string.

You have the right idea in example #2 of skipping the first row. Note however that 1.3.0 is a rather old version (I have 1.6.1). In newer versions `skiprows` is deprecated and you should use `skip_header` instead.

The reason that the shape of the array is `(373,)` is that it is a structured array (see http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html), which is what numpy uses to represent inhomogeneous data. So `data[10]` gives you an entire row of your table. You can also access the data columns by name, for example `data['f10']`. You can find the names of the columns in `data.dtype.names`. It is also possible to use the original column names that are defined in the first line of your data file:

```
 data = genfromtxt("fMdRjRMv.txt", dtype=None, delimiter=',', names=True)
```

then you can access a column like `data['Age']`.

Comment: Thanks hugely, this is incredibly useful. I hope you wouldn't mind answering these two follow ups: (1) How can I access a specific value within the structured array [say the 3rd entry in the 10th row]? and (2) is there a way to reshape the array to turn it into a 373x15 shape? Thanks hugely again.

Comment: OK, well, I answered question (1) myself. Simply data['Age'][10] would do the trick.

Comment: @DanEvans: as to your second follow-up, I am afraid that you can't force it to be a regular numpy array so long as the columns have different data types. So if you want the entire table, then everything would have to be a string, as in your original example #1, which is probably not very useful to you. Alternatively, you could select only the numerical columns and force them all to be floats. P.S. If you found my answer useful, then please consider accepting it and/or upvoting it.

Comment: Thanks very much! I really appreciate your time. I've 'accepted' your answer by clicking on the tick mark. Unfortunately my status isn't high enough to upvote it, but hopefully another user will help out!